# Group by 3 hour interval in mysql

Tags: mysql, intervals

I'm trying to get the 3 hour interval of my data. This is my query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000, '%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p') as t_stamp,
  AVG(CASE WHEN id = '1' THEN float END) Col1,  
  AVG(CASE WHEN id = '2' THEN float END) Col2,
  AVG(CASE WHEN id = '3' THEN float END) Col3,  
  AVG(CASE WHEN id = '4' THEN float END) Col4,
  AVG(CASE WHEN id = '5' THEN float END) Col5,  
  AVG(CASE WHEN id = '6' THEN float END) Col6

FROM database
WHERE id IN ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6") and 

DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) BETWEEN '2014-03-31'
AND '2014-04-01'
and value is not null

GROUP BY
DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), HOUR(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), MINUTE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) 
DIV 15
```

I can get the interval up to 1 hour but when I needed to get the 3 hour data I changed DIV 15 to DIV 180 but didn't get the 
right output, the data still showed 1 hour interval.

I thought that I could just change DIV easily.

We are using unix timestamps in out tstamp columns and unfortunately I can't/not allowed to edit the columns structure.

Comment: You are going to make this much more painful that necessary unless you start using MySQL datetime or timestamp field types instead of using unix timestamps.

Comment: unfortunately i can't edit the timestamps structure in my table.